# Xcode Test General Pane

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I am wondering what the “Target” pop-up menu in the General pane for an XCTest bundle does. It lists the other targets in the project, as well as a “None” option. I thought that this pop-up menu is used to select the target being tested so that the tests will automatically be run after every build of that target, but nothing of the sort happens.

Changing the selected menu item has no effect that I can find (including a change to my project file). What does this feature do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You partially answered your own question. The Target pop-up menu selects the target being tested. You should set it to your application target (or whatever target you want to test). Xcode 5 removed the ability to automatically run tests after building the application target.

I'm surprised changing the selected menu item had no effect for you. When I choose None from the Target pop-up menu, my tests fail.